# SQLAlchemy retriving a specific value and convert to an INT

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the price value from my EVENTS class as an INT so that I can use it to make a booking by multiplying by the number of attendees for an event when I insert a new row in the booking table.

Tables in databse

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    host = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    event_title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    event_description = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    movie_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    movie_description = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    genre = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    movie_start_time = db.Column(db.Time(), nullable=False)
    movie_end_time = db.Column(db.Time(), nullable=False)
    classification = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    actors = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    directors = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    event_date = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False)
    published_date = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False) 
    published_by = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    capacity = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    
    # ... Create the Comments db.relationship
    # relation to call destination.comments and comment.destination
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='event')


    
class Booking(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bookings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    attendees = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    total_price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    booked_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    # foreign key
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id'))
```

Code calling from Events table to get `price` and insert new row into `Booking` table

```
price = Event.query.with_entities(Event.price).filter_by(id = event)
      user_name = User.query.with_entities(User.id).filter_by(name = current_user.name)
      num_attendees = forms.attendees.data
      print(num_attendees)
      print(type(price))
      booking = Booking(attendees=forms.attendees.data,
                        total_price= price * num_attendees,
                        user_id = user_name,
                        event_id = event) 
      #here the back-referencing works - comment.destination is set
      # and the link is created
      db.session.add(booking) 
      db.session.commit()
```

But I keep running into errors such as `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Row' and 'int'`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scalar()` to get the first column of the first result:

```py
price = Event.query.with_entities(Event.price).filter_by(id = event).scalar()
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar